# What is the official pronunciation for "Cursed Child"?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child

I have heard it both ways; some say "kerst" while others say "ker-sid". How do they pronounce it in the play?

**Which is the *official* pronunciation?**

Comment: Asking which is the "correct" pronunciation is merely a matter of dialects of English, and not a question pertaining to the fictional universe. The video you cite here notes that the pronunciation emphasizing the -ed is old-fashioned, and that either may be used. Even within the Potterverse, different speakers of English, within Britain and without, will pronounce the adjective "cursed" differently. "How do they pronounce it in the play" is certainly a valid question, but it may turn out that different actors pronounce it differently - I don't think it can be called "official" either way.

Comment: I am inclined to agree.  It is just a regional or idiolectic difference.

Comment: Interestingly, according to the Oxford Learner's Dictionary 'kerst' means literally under a curse, while 'ker-sid' means annoying or irritating (http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cursed). I've never heard that claimed anywhere else, I'm highly sceptical of it and OED doesn't agree, but the OLD *is* produced by OUP. Hmm. Could be worth a cross-post to English.SE.

Comment: @tardigrade more likely migrated

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Yeah, let's migrate. This is really more an issue of English pronunciation.

Comment: I disagree. Asking how the show title is to be ***officially*** pronounced is very much on topic

Comment: @Valorum -  I think it's a bit like asking "How does one officially pronounce 'the' in 'Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2'?" Is this *really* relevant fandom information?

Comment: @Adamant - I would imagine that the prospect of mispronouncing the title (and appearing foolish to other fans) would make most fans shudder.

Comment: I can get behind something like [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112401/the-correct-pronunciation-of-hermione?rq=1) or [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27610/what-is-the-correct-pronunciation-of-beauxbatons?rq=1), because this is grammar specific to the work, not to mention a question that many people have. But the pronunciation of any which word in the title of a science fiction or fantasy work? No.

Comment: @Adamant - I recall speaking to someone who stated that they were a "*a true Potterhead*" and realising a few minutes into the conversation that they didn't know how Hermione was pronounced. I found it rather droll (and still do) but I'm guessing that they look back on that conversation and shudder.

Comment: If they wanted it to be _kur-sed_ it would have been easy (and effective) to put a grave accent over the e in "Cursèd"

Comment: I can see @Valorum's point; as a specific question about this title I suppose this does belong here. I've posted the broader question of 'what determines how cursed should be pronounced' on English.SE (with a link back here, so there may be some cross-traffic): http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/340837/what-determines-how-cursed-as-an-attributive-adjective-is-pronounced

Comment: @Valorum maybe they were making a Krummy joke?

Comment: @tardigrade - I almost showed them the dumbledoor.

Comment: I'm with Dick here. VTLO.

Answer (score 9):

Sam Clemmett (the actor who portrays Albus Potter) refers to it as *cur-sed* (curr-sedd).

Whereas JKR herself pronounces it as *cursed* ("*kirst*")

Comment: In other words, pretty much individual pronunciation?

Comment: I just phoned the theatre. The nice lady I spoke to said they'd been told that it was **"Harry Potter and the *'kurr-sid'* child"** by their boss.

Comment: @Valorum I'd add that into the answer. :) Also, I've listened to Sam say it in that 1st video over and over, and each time it sounds like "kirst" (1-syllable) to me.